# Display hyphenation options for a specific word

Tags: tex-core, hyphenation, logging

When TeX produces Overfull box, is puts something like this in the log:

```
Overfull \hbox (15.47195pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 7--9
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 I re-ally re-ally want to get dis-played the op-tions for 
hy-phen-ation xxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
```

I would like a macro `\showhyphens` that would for an entry like `\showhyphens{hyphenation}` display its hyphenation options, i.e. `hy-phen-ation`. This should be displayed either in the document (preferred) or in the log.

*(Background: I need this for sumbitting a paper that contains many multi-part words and similar stuff like `$(2,3)$-representation` etc. I know that there are ways to modify `-` with `\discretionary` to make the word breakable, but it makes the code extremly unreadable and I'm not allowed to make this a macro definition.)*

Comment: Some old TUGboat articles did it in a paragraph, I guess with Plain. Are those macros available somewhere?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Bing!  Your wish has been granted.

Seriously: `\showhyphens` already exists under that exact same name.

Comment: Unbelievable! Still, I'm curious if someone has a solution that avoids the need to check the log file.

Comment: @tohecz -- I tend to use the `\showhyphens` tool interactively (using the steps listed in the TeXBook): First, type `tex` (not `latex`) in an open command window, and you'll get a `**` prompt; at the `**` prompt type `\relax`, and you'll get a `*` (single-asterisk) prompt. At the `*` prompt, type `\showhyphens{hyphenation}` (or whatever words you're interested in) and watch TeX's output. Whey you're done, type `\bye` to exit TeX. :-)  On your second observation: I'm not aware of a variant of the `\showhyphens` command that does *not* write its output to the log file.

Comment: @Mico sounds great! That is the solution I wanted. (I did not think it's TeX command not LaTeX and even though I'm aware of the interactive mode, this usage of it is hilarious!)

Comment: Note that `\showhyphens` won't work with XeLaTeX if the current font is an OpenType one. The package `xltxtra` redefines the command, but the words must be separated by commas, rather than spaces.

Comment: @Mico How do you tell `tex` the language?

Comment: @cfr - it depends very much on the TeX engine. This is a *really good question*, by the way. I'd like to suggest that you pose it as a *new* question.

Comment: @Mico Thanks. See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218290/how-can-i-display-the-hyphenation-patterns-for-a-language-other-than-us-english).

Comment: Interactively:  `echo "\showhyphens{slartibartfast}" | tex`.  For even fewer keystrokes, wrap that into a bash alias and, while you're at it, tidy up the output with `| tail -n +4 | head -n -10`.

Answer (score 30):

Ok, here is the answer for *printing* the hyphens:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\def\rehbox{{\unskip\unpenalty\setbox0\lastbox\ifhbox0 \rehbox
    \hbox{\unhbox0} \else \leavevmode \fi}}
\newcommand\printhyphens[1]{%
  \setbox0\vbox{{%
      \pretolerance-1\hsize=0pt\hfuzz=\maxdimen
      \noindent\hspace*{0pt}#1\par\rehbox}\par}%
  \unvbox 0
}

\begin{document}
\printhyphens{If you cannot reconsider this proposal, you are
  incompatible, my dearest friend.}
\end{document}
```

As the first version is limited by its usage of the save stack, here is a version that isn't.  However, as stated in the comments, it is O(n^3), so it will become inefficient for large arguments rather fast, and the whole point of not using the save stack is to be able to *use* large arguments.  So it would really make more sense to first split the input into words or lines and process them one by one, using a call of the first version of `\printhyphens`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\def\rehbox{\unskip\unpenalty\setbox2\lastbox\ifhbox2
  \setbox0\hbox{\hbox{\unhbox2} \unhbox0}\expandafter\rehbox\fi}
\newcommand\printhyphens[1]{%
  \setbox0\vbox{{\setbox0\hbox{}%
      \pretolerance-1\hsize=0pt\hfuzz=\maxdimen
      \noindent\hspace*{0pt}#1\par\rehbox\unhbox0}\par}%
  \unvbox 0
}

\begin{document}
\printhyphens{If you cannot reconsider this proposal, you are
  incompatible, my dearest friend.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a great little program! However, if there are more than about 140 words in the argument of the `\printhyphen` statement, the program crashes with a "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels = 255]" message. Is there a way to make the `\rehbox` statement non-recursive?

Comment: Not without a complete rewrite with a huge loss of performance (instead of storing the boxes on the save stack, about O(n), you would have to append them to a global box, O(n^3)).  It would likely make more sense to feed it one word at a time.  Which reminds me: you might need \hspace*{0pt} after \noindent to have the first word hyphenated as well.

Comment: Thanks, David. I suspected there was a very good reason you'd implemented the program the way you did!

Comment: The documentation (version 2.19) of the `soul` package contains yet another method in section 7.3: http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/soul/soul.pdf

Answer (score 26):

With LuaTeX you have two options: `\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}` gives a lot of information whereas `\usepackage{showhyphens}` marks only all possible hyphenation points.

See http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/lualatex/showhyphens/showhyphens-doc.pdf

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Because I know that OP (yo) understand Czech then I can refer the book "TeXbook naruby" (full text available on the internet [here](http://petr.olsak.net/tbn.html)), page 225 below and page 226. The macro `\showhyphenpar` is presented here. The paragraph after `\showhyphenpar` is printed with all words shown as hy-phen-ated.

```
\def\showhyphenpar{\bgroup  
   \def\par{\setparams\endgraf\composelines}
   \setbox0=\vbox\bgroup \noindent\hskip0pt\relax}
\def\setparams{\rightskip=0pt plus1fil
   \linepenalty=1000 \pretolerance=-1 \hyphenpenalty=-10000}
\def\composelines{\setbox2=\hbox{}%
   \loop \setbox0=\lastbox \unskip \unpenalty
   \ifhbox0 % je už \vbox vyprázdněn?
     \global\setbox2=\hbox{\unhbox0\unskip\unhbox2}
   \repeat
   \egroup % vyprázdněný \vbox ukončím
   \exhyphenpenalty=10000 % \box2 vyšoupnu do vnějšího seznamu
   \emergencystretch=4em \leavevmode\unhbox2 \endgraf\egroup}
```

The principles of this macro is described in the TeXbook naruby.

Comment: Díky[.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232251/11002)