# Hyphenation of bold font

Tags: pdftex, lyx, hyphenation, hyphenat

I am getting unexpected hyphenation behavior when using bold font. Below is the output using normal font.

[image]

Below is when using bold font. Note that font is not justified on the right side.

[image]

Source code for the above in Lyx:

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass report
\options a4paper,12pt,twoside
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\branch Run from Main
\selected 1
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\branch Run from Here
\selected 0
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\branch a
\selected 0
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\branch b
\selected 1
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\branch c
\selected 0
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\branch PrivateInfo
\selected 0
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\branch Private Info
\selected 1
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\branch Prematter
\selected 0
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\branch blocked.sty
\selected 1
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\branch boxit.sty
\selected 1
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\branch uhead.sty
\selected 1
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\branch icthesis.sty
\selected 1
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\branch mathchars.sty
\selected 1
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 2
\tocdepth 2
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard

\series bold
something something something something something something something something
 something something something something something something something something
 something something something something something something something something
 something something something something something something 
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Below is when using mixed normal and bold font. I don't what is the basis for hyphenation.

[image]

Source code for the above in Lyx :

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass report
\options a4paper,12pt,twoside
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\branch Run from Main
\selected 1
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\branch Run from Here
\selected 0
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\branch a
\selected 0
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\branch b
\selected 1
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\branch c
\selected 0
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\branch PrivateInfo
\selected 0
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\branch Private Info
\selected 1
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\branch Prematter
\selected 0
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\branch blocked.sty
\selected 1
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\branch boxit.sty
\selected 1
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\branch uhead.sty
\selected 1
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\branch icthesis.sty
\selected 1
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\branch mathchars.sty
\selected 1
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 2
\tocdepth 2
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\align block
something something something 
\series bold
something something something something something something something something
 something something 
\series default
something something something 
\series bold
something something something something something something something 
\series default
something something something 
\series bold
something something something something 
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

This is affecting my report. Below is a screenshot from my report.

[image]

There is also another issue I am facing with hyphenation. Text that is already hyphenated is not hyphenated again which makes a bit sense but breaks the paragraph alignment.

[image]

By the way, I am using Lyx. Please advise.

Regards,
Meshaal

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your posting describes an issue. In order for readers to have a chance to *diagnose* the cause(s) of the issue, more information is required. Please augment your code snippets -- starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` -- to make them compilable.

Comment: Incidentally, should it be permissible to hyphenate the word "VMware" (presumably after "VM")?

Comment: `Insert` → `Formating` → `Hyphenation point` with the cursor after "VM". The Code Preview Pane (menu View) should show `VM\-preview` (the same approach  for  `preserva\-tion`)  For the MWE asked for Mico, just remove as far as possible the irrelevant parts for the issue in the Lyx document   (figures, title, etc.) and just copy the code showed in the Code Preview Pane.

Comment: Regarding hyphenation of words that already contain a hyphen, see [Why can words with hyphen char not be hyphenated?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63232/579)

Comment: @Mico I have updated the source codes.

Comment: I hope I don't rely on manual hyphenation since I frequently change the (bindingoffset). Although I tried manual hyphenation, it only works on normal text. It was no effect on bold font. I am looking for an automatic, or at least semi-automatic approach, to handle that.

Comment: I apologize for not providing MWE for the last two cases. It takes time to provide them since they are part of a large report. I don't feel it is necessary to replicating MWE for those cases as I will rely on replicating the solution that we hopefully discover for the provided MWEs to the report. Provided MWEs are highly correlated to the report, but more focused on the problem in hand.