# Why is it useful to change \hyphenchar?

Tags: hyphenation

In `il2code.tex` there is such text:

```
%% Alternative \hyphenchar ("je-li" is no "je\hyphenchar li").
\chardef\extrahyphenchar=156
\def\extrahyphens{%
  \hyphenchar\tenrm=\extrahyphenchar
  \hyphenchar\tenbf=\extrahyphenchar
  \hyphenchar\tentt=\extrahyphenchar
  \hyphenchar\tensl=\extrahyphenchar
  \hyphenchar\tenit=\extrahyphenchar
  \defaulthyphenchar=\extrahyphenchar}
```

What is the benefit of this?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63232/4427

Comment: Side note, the behavior of LuaTeX regarding hyphenation is different. There are `\exhyphenchar` (*explicit*ly specified hyphen char) and `\prehyphenchar`, `\preexhyphenchar` etc., so setting `\hyphenchar` is almost no-op in LuaTeX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compile with `pdfcsplain`:

```
\hsize=0pt \parindent=0pt

\hskip0pt supercalifragilistic-expialidocious

\extrahyphens
\lccode`-=`- % so - does not block hyphenation

\hskip0pt supercalifragilistic-expialidocious

\bye
```

In the first case, the hyphen coincides with the `\hyphenchar`, so the word is only split at the hyphen. In the second case, the hyphen doesn't block hyphenation (in the word part preceding it). With `` \lccode`-=`- `` we allow hyphenation also after the explicit hyphen (well, this is not really the best thing to do, as you see).

[image]

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63234/4427

Comment: "this is not really the best thing to do" - this can be solved with the help of ligature "〈hyphen〉〈hyphenchar〉 ⟶ 〈hyphenchar〉".

Comment: I wonder why `\discretionary{-}{}{-}` does not work here.