# Linebreak before a link

Tags: hyperref, line-breaking, hyperlink

In German, abbreviations can be part of compound words that need to be hyphenated, like "Java-API".

My problem is that when I write `Java-\gls{api}`, I never get a line break after the hyphen. I managed to find out that the problem is not the abbreviation, but the hyperlink, and that it occurs with all kinds of links and is reproducable without glossaries.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\overfullrule=1mm
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nogroupskip,toc=true]{glossaries}
\usepackage[abbreviations]{glossaries-extra}
\newabbreviation{api}{API}{Application Programming Interface}
\begin{document}
    \gls{api}

    xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxx Java-\gls{api} xxxxxx

    xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxx Java-API xxxxxx

    xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxx Java-\url{xxx} xxxxxx
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I allow a line break between `Java-` and the hyperlink?

I'm using hyperref 2019/09/28 v7.00a with LuaLaTeX 1.10.0 from TexLive 2019.52579 on Arch Linux.

Comment: I get a line break with your example. How do you compile and is your tex system up-to-date?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer please see the edit

Comment: If you are writing in German, you are probably loading `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`, in which case `Java"=\gls{api}` apparently works. `"=` instead of `-` may be a good idea anyway, in case you have longer compounds like `Dampfschifffahrts"=API`. (Cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2706/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63232/35864)

Comment: I'm using babel, but without the shorthands (they cause too many issues with other packages for me). I can confirm that it works with `\hyp` from the `hyphenat` package, but it's not really satisfactory.