# Is there a way to tell if LaTeX knows how to hyphenate a word?

Tags: hyphenation

I regularly write chemistry documents with odd words in them. Is there a way to know if LaTeX knows it can hyphenate a word? I'm wondering as the person beside me just discovered that the person whose thesis he is using as a base told LaTeX how to hyphenate *polymer*, which he thought would be common enough that LaTeX would know it already.

Comment: `tex<enter>\showhyphens{polymer}` gives `poly-mer` here. Maybe you use some customisations which prevent the hyphenation in this case.

Comment: @marco So I can enter any word and see if it needs a custom definition?

Comment: hyphenation actually depends on what language (and associated patterns) are in effect.  if `babel` is being used with a language other than u.s. english, the results may be different.  in any event, `\showhyphens{...}` when requested in the same environment (but without any additional `\hyphenation{...}` exceptions) should give the canonical result.

Comment: Duplicate? [Display hyphenation options for a specific word](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55282/11002) (Yep, it's my question, that's how I know so quickly that it exists `;)`)