# LaTeX: display hyphenation and justification problems

Tags: hyphenation, debugging, draft

(At least) The `article`, `report` and `book` classes support the option `draft`, which displays hyphenation and justification problems with a black square, but also does not load figures. I could have the latter without the former, but can I also only have (at least something like) the black squares, but still load figures?

A bonus would be to display the possible hypenation points [as possible in LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55509/18240) for pdflatex.

Comment: `\usepackage[final]{graphicx}` will override the global `draft` option.

Comment: Regarding your second query: I don't think it's possible to get the equivalent of the `showhyphens` package under pdflatex. For one, pdftex cannot hyphenate the first word of a paragraph, *any* paragraph. Second, `showhyphens` also makes direct use of the specialized hyphenation algorithm of luatex, which operates quite differently from that of pdftex.

Comment: You can say e.g. `\showhyphens {magnificent tautology}` and it will show you the possible hyphenation points in `magnificent tautology`.

Comment: @Mico it's probably worth saying that "pdftex cannot hyphenate the first word of a paragraph" doesn't mean that pdftex can't hyphenate the thing a human reader would think of as the first word of the paragraph, just that it won't hyphenate a word that is at the start of a horizontal list, but a zero width space before the word is enough to allow hyphenation again) (true showhyphens is lua though:-)

Comment: There is also [testhyphens](http://ctan.org/pkg/testhyphens).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Maybe the bigger question is whether it can be reasonably assumed that an author is willing to insert `\hspace{0pt}` (or the equivalent thereof) at the start of each and every paragraph of the document, just to enable hyphenation of the paragraphs' "real" first words.

Comment: @Mico My mental model of German is that English Paragraph = German Word and it's needed all the time:-) (authors don't need to do it but packages can set up `\everypar` to add it (with care)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to display the black box that indicates overfull lines without any of the other
side effects of the `[draft]` option, put this in your preamble:

```
\setlength\overfullrule{5pt}
```

you can reset this at any time within your document.  setting it to a value of `0pt`
makes it disappear.

the package `testhyphens` suggested by @cfr is also a
very useful tool for checking blocks of text *in situ*; it seems not so attractive
to apply to an entire document in a single go.