# How can I display the possible hyphenation points for words in a language other than US English?

Tags: tex-core, languages, hyphenation

This is a follow-up to [tohecz's question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55282/), which I'm asking at the suggestion of [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55282/display-hyphenation-options-for-a-specific-word/55283?noredirect=1#comment511576_55283).

The original question asks how to discover the hyphenation points for particular words, and the answers explain how to do this in various ways and for various engines.

For example, [user9588's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55283/) introduces `\showhyphens` and [Mico's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55282/display-hyphenation-options-for-a-specific-word/55283?noredirect=1#comment115670_55283) explains how to use the command interactively.

So, here's a sample session:

```
$ tex
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=tex)
**\relax

*\showhyphens{un casgliad credadwy traddodiadau athroniaeth mathemateg canolfan hapusrwydd blwyddyn deuddeg llongyfarchiadau cyfeiriadau}

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line 0
[] \tenrm un cas-gliad credadwy trad-do-di-adau athro-ni-aeth math-e-mateg cano
l-fan ha-pus-r-wydd blwyd-dyn deud-deg llongy-farchi-adau cyfeiri-adau

*\bye
(see the transcript file for additional information)
No pages of output.
Transcript written on texput.log.
```

Now, there is clearly a problem because these are not necessarily the *correct* hyphenation points. For example, `dd` is a single letter, yet TeX is splitting `traddodiadau`, `blwyddyn` and `deuddeg` in the middle of that letter.

The problem is not that the correct hyphenation patterns are unavailable:

[image: Welsh hyphenation patterns]

As can be seen, `traddodiadau` and `deuddeg` are split correctly in this output and, in general, the words are split at points which are not predicted by the sample session with `\showhyphens`.

The problem is that TeX needs to load the correct hyphenation patterns and to apply the correct set for the active language:

```
\documentclass[welsh,a6paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[hscale=.25]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    un casgliad credadwy traddodiadau athroniaeth mathemateg canolfan hapusrwydd blwyddyn deuddeg llongyfarchiadau cyfeiriadau
\end{document}
```

**How can I display the possible hyphenation points for words in a language other than US English?**

I've used a non-English example above, but the same question will also apply to other variants of English. For example, British hyphenation patterns differ from the American ones. (Compare the results of `\showhyphens{favourite}` and `\showhyphens{favorite}`, for example.)

Comment: Do you want a solution for plain? We are going to be a bit limited for Kunth's TeX as the format doesn't build in most of the hyphenation patterns.

Comment: `\showhyphens` can be used within a latex file, where you can easily set the desired language (presumably using `babel`).  you'll just have to take the trouble to go through the extra step of creating a file and processing that.  if you're going to be doing a lot of this over a long period of time, it might be worthwhile creating a language-specific format that could be used interactively, but it's been so long since i've done that, that i've forgotten how.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `testhyphens` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british,welsh]{babel}
\usepackage{testhyphens}

\begin{document}

\begin{checkhyphens}{}
un casgliad credadwy traddodiadau athroniaeth mathemateg canolfan
hapusrwydd blwyddyn deuddeg llongyfarchiadau cyfeiriadau
\end{checkhyphens}

\selectlanguage{british}

\begin{checkhyphens}{}
un casgliad credadwy traddodiadau athroniaeth mathemateg canolfan
hapusrwydd blwyddyn deuddeg llongyfarchiadau cyfeiriadau
\end{checkhyphens}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Thank you! I'd never heard of this. [Probably I should accept this but the number of answers so far makes me think I should wait just to see what people dream up!]

Comment: @cfr The advantage of this package is that it works also with XeLaTeX, while `\showhyphens` doesn't; you can load `xltxtra`, but the `\showhyphens` it defines has a different syntax (requires a comma separated list of words).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using a plain-like format with the `babel` hyphenation patterns available (so say `pdftex` or `xetex`) you can switch to the correct hyphenation using the fact that `\lang@<name>` is the language number. Thus

```
\language\csname lang@welsh\endcsname
\showhyphens{un casgliad credadwy traddodiadau athroniaeth mathemateg canolfan hapusrwydd blwyddyn deuddeg llongyfarchiadau cyfeiriadau}
\bye
```

gives

```
[] \tenrm un casgl-iad cred-adwy tra-ddod-iadau athron-iaeth math-emateg canol-
fan hapus-rwydd blwyddyn deu-ddeg llon-gy-farch-iadau cyf-eir-iadau
```

If you want to use LaTeX then you want `\l@<name>` rather than `\lang@<name>`, plus you need at least the start of a document

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\language\csname l@welsh\endcsname
\showhyphens{un casgliad credadwy traddodiadau athroniaeth mathemateg canolfan hapusrwydd blwyddyn deuddeg llongyfarchiadau cyfeiriadau}
```

Comment: (+1) Thanks. I'm actually using pdfLaTeX (mostly). But I don't care if I need to use something different to get the patterns.

Comment: Well your example was plain so I went with that: `\lang@...` is not defined for LaTeX, but you could use `\l@...` if you want to avoid the 'full fat' of loading `babel` just for an interactive test

Comment: for latex, you could create a dummy input file, ending before entering `\showhyphens`.  i'd be inclined to add a note that will type out, something like `\message{Enter words in braces, beginning with \string\showhyphens and finish with \string\end\string{document\string} when you are done.  The results will be preserved in your log file.}`.  i'm sure this can be made spiffier, to show just the actual words with hyphens; i'll dig into my "exception list" tugboat article, but not right away.

Answer (score 4):

here's an adaptation of your file that will generate the hyphenations you seek:

```
\documentclass[welsh]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\showhyphens{un casgliad credadwy traddodiadau athroniaeth}

\showhyphens{mathemateg canolfan hapusrwydd blwyddyn}

\showhyphens{deuddeg llongyfarchiadau cyfeiriadau}

\end{document}
```

just process this with latex, and look in the log for the results:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 7--7
[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 un casgl-iad cred-adwy tra-ddod-iadau athron-iaeth

\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x16383.99998, glue set 1938.74178 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 9--9
[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 math-emateg canol-fan hapus-rwydd blwyddyn

\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x16383.99998, glue set 2425.43556 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 11--11
[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 deu-ddeg llon-gy-farch-iadau cyf-eir-iadau

\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x16383.99998, glue set 3240.64192 []
```

Comment: (+1) Thanks. Is there a way to not have to go through the log file to find these? The interactive method suggested to Mico was a response to somebody asking this in the 'standard' case, so I was hoping for a similar solution for other languages.

Comment: @cfr You can run LaTeX interactively too :-) See my updated answer: a bit tedious to have to type in the first couple of lines.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks. I used that just because it seemed a really easy and straightforward method. Sorry if I wasn't clear.