# Generate the hyphenation of a given list of words

Tags: hyphenation, automation

I'm new to LaTeX; is there a way to tell the TeX engine to generate the hyphenation of a given list of words as a text output file? For example:

```
abdomen
abduction
aberrance
...
```

What I want is something like:

```
ab-domen
ab-duc-tion
aber-rance
...
```

possibly as text.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: After poking around a little I noticed that something was off and found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218290/how-can-i-display-the-possible-hyphenation-points-for-words-in-a-language-other) about `\showhyphens` using the wrong hyphenation patterns in different languages, so... be aware of this.

Comment: well as I said, `\showhyphens` shows the patterns in use _at that point_ so you need to select the language first

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\showhyphens` writes this to the terminal and log:

```
\documentclass{article}

\showhyphens{
abdomen
abduction
aberrance
}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Produces a log file with

```
[]  \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ab-domen ab-duc-tion aber-rance
```

Comment: Actually, what if I want to use a different language other than English?

Comment: @giofrida just set the language as you would normally before `\showhyphens`  `\usepackage[french]{babel}` or whatever you use. You can use `\showhyphens` multiple times within the document and it will show the hyphenation active at that point

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should ask another question, but both `\showhyphens` and `\begin{checkhyphens}` give the wrong hyphenation, meaning that if I select my language, the hyphenation is actually different and "more" correct, but not on all words. In fact, if I remove the corresponding `hyph-***.tex` file from its folder (`hyph-utf8`), then the hyphenation still works the same, possibly meaning that the file was never used in the first place?

Comment: hard to say without more information, but say `\makeatletter\show\l@italian` will show `\char...` if Italian is loaded in the fomat @giofrida

Comment: Well, yes, I get `\l@italian=\char"23` in the console output, though it shows even without the file in place. Not that it means anything, but still.

Comment: @giofrida so you have italian patterns loaded unless something very strange. make sure you are using T1 encoding in pdftex  or TU in luatex or xetex. Otherwise make a new question with a complete example

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of ways to do this.

With LuaLaTeX, you can use the `showhyphenation` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showhyphenation}
\begin{document}
%\parbox{0pt}{%
    abdomen
    abduction
    aberrance
%}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also place the words in a `parbox` of zero width. Each word (except the first word in some engines) will automatically line break at each of its hyphenation points.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\parbox{0pt}{%
    abdomen
    abduction
    aberrance
}
\end{document}
```

[image]